# Acthor string can't be found in pdf but can be in word by using docsign

Tags: java

The Code:

```
    SignHere signHere = new SignHere();
    signHere.setDocumentId("1");
    signHere.setPageNumber("1");
    signHere.setRecipientId("1");
    signHere.setAnchorString("LiangJiacheng");
    signHere.setTabLabel("SignHereTab");
```

By using Word:

[image: by using word]

By using PDF:

[image: by using pdf]

I have already used "setAnchorCaseSensitive" and "setAnchorIgnoreIfNotPresent".But the tag is always on upper left corner in pdf

Comment: Please add description in the question itself. Don't add images as link.